# Magento 2.3.4 - 5 Not working with PHP 7.2 - 7.3 but working fine on PHP 7.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, server-setup

Could someone please help me ? I have newly setup VPS server, and as per Magento 2 requirements, I need PHP 7.2 or 7.3 to run Magento 2.3.4 - 5.

I'm getting an error when I run Magneto 2.3.4 on PHP 7.3. But Magento 2.3.4 is working fine on PHP 7.1 which is totally baseless.

Is there someone facing the same issue ? Can someone help me about what I am doing wrong on the new VPS server?

Answer (score 0):

Check all server required extension for the php version and magento version. 
It should work with latest php version